# Obtain data from a form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, button

I'm building a wordpress website using Avada tamplate. I use the Avada login form in which the users insert their username and password. I would like to get the username of the user when he click on the form button and he's redirect to login.php page. I don't understand why I can't do that. 
The code of the form (i removed "class" and "style" in order to reduce it) is:

```html
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" method="post" action="http://www.mywebsite.com/es/wp-login.php">
    <div>
        <div>
            <label for="user_login">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="log" placeholder="Username" value="" size="20" id="user_login" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" value="" id="user_pass" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="wp-submit">Log in</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="login.php" />
            <input type="hidden" name="fusion_login_box" value="true" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/es/area-privada/" /><span></span></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The login.php code is very simple:

```php
<?php
    $username = $_POST['log'];
    echo $username;
?>
```

however the variable $username is blank and doesn't capture the username. Someone can help me please? thanks!

Comment: Since you're using Wordpress, I'd rather go with either of these hooks/actions: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/ for successful logins, or https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login_failed/ for failed logins. In both cases, you receive the username supplied as the first function argument.

Comment: Most likely, in case you meant the successful login, WordPress redirects you to a page (specified as `redirect_to` field). That would explain why you can no longer get the `'log'` parameter, since it's not carried along with the redirect.